# Is There a List/Chart for Javascript Speeds?

Tags: javascript, performance

In the Javascript world, I know there is talk over which is more important.  The way your code looks, and the speed at which it moves.  I've been looking and have yet to find any kind of comparison chart, between any/all javascript/es speeds.

Is there a chart or list somewhere that you know of that shows the comparison of speed over different pieces of functionality?  Or would you be someone interested enough in making one to share?

**Example:** *For Loops work faster than calling a Function multiple times.*

I Myself, am personally interested.  I've obviously seen or read a few things here and there, and have experimented with some functionality.  But I wouldn't mind an overall cheat sheet for when I'm tackling a large project and trying to plan out the overall approach.

If you also have any suggestions to books that might explain this a bit better I'd be interested in those as well.  I've got a few on design patterns, but they only cover so much in this aspect/area.

Comment: There's a website, http://jsperf.com/ , which has many performance tests logged over the years. It's been used a lot here on SO to demonstrate code comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love this Website, it allows you to write tests also:

https://jsperf.com

You can see the latest 250 test here or search one:

https://jsperf.com/browse